# Break line in message thrown by custom Exception in Java

Tags: java, jsp, exception, error-handling, struts2

I need to break line between my message thrown by custom `Exception`.

I'm using Struts 2 `addActionError()` and the error  message will be displayed on JSP.

**So here is my Java code:**

```
if (result_Of_Scan.equals("ERROR")) {
    throw new AdserverException("We are getting problem with connecting our " 
                    + "Antivirus Server! Please try  again after some time");
}
```

So I need to show `"We are getting problem with connecting our Antivirus Server"` on first line and  `"Please try  again after some time"` on next line on the browser.

I have tried `\n`, `<br>` and `&ltbr&gt` but they are not working.

Comment: Exception messages should not contain any formatting information that is dedicated for being displayed. I even recommend to not use the exception message as a GUI message. Let your GUI take the exception (and maybe let it read the `exception.getMessage()`) to have it show a proper failure message. Parsing the exception message and assembling the GUI message is the responsibility of the GUI, only.

Comment: Where do you use `addAction`? How do you display this in jsp?

Comment: The above code is in Util class which Im calling from Action class and using it in following way in jsp
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
 <div class="alert_msg alert">
  <s:actionerror />
 </div>
</s:if>

Answer (score 1):

To display the message on the new line in JSP you should use `<br>`. It didn't display on the new line when you have tried it because  [`<s:actionerror>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/actionerror-tag.html) by default escapes html. You should use `escape="false"` attribute to change the output to allow rendering html.

```jsp
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()"> <div class="alert_msg alert"> <s:actionerror escape="false"/> </div> </s:if>
```

Comment: But in this way I have to change hasActionError for  each and every jsp files which contains File Upload option.